# Undefined method each for nil:NilClass in erb template

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to loop through and array and have checked to make sure it is being passed correctly to the template, yet am hitting the error.

The template:

```
<% if defined?(source[:blacklist]) %>
   "blacklist": [
    <% source[:blacklist].each do |listed| %>
    "<%= listed %>"
    <% end %>
  ],
<% end %>
```

output of source[:blacklist] when no loop:

```
"[\"/var/log/httpd/access.log*\", \"/var/log/httpd/error.log*\", \"/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log\", \"/var/log/httpd/access_log\", \"/var/log/httpd/error_log\"]"
```

error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not present, if it was it would actually be a string.

Using `defined?(source[:blacklist])` presents an issue as it will return true if it's not an array, e.g. `defined? nil` is `"nil"` which is truthy.

#### Step 1: convert to array

If you cannot change how the data is being generated, parse it into a Ruby array, defaulting to an empty array if there is an unexpected data or none at all.

`blacklist = source[:blacklist].gsub(/(\­[\"|\"\])/­, '').s­plit('", "') || []`

#### Step 2: loop if the array exists and with content

`<% if not blacklist.empty? %>`

Comment: I do have the ability to modify the data being generated but I guess I'm not sure why or how it's not being passed as an array.  I have it defined as: 
`node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] = [
  "/var/log/httpd/access.log*",
  "/var/log/httpd/error.log*",
  "/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log",
  "/var/log/httpd/access_log",
  "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
]`  and then passed directly into the template with `variables({
      :sources => node[:server][:sumologic][:sources]
  })`

Comment: So you're defining a ruby array, assigning it to a variable and in the view it is now a string? Have you tried using the two lines I mentioned with any success?

Answer (score 0):

If `source[:blacklist]` is nil then `defined? source[:blacklist]` will return the string "method" and that's "truthy".

So it will fall through and you'll get the error you see... `Undefined method each for nil:NilClass`

When you say "output of source with no loop"... is that in the controller or did you check the output in the erb file? It could be the value's not being passed to the erb, and you typically want to use instance variables to pass data to html.erb files.

Also, you should note that the output you show for `source[:blacklist]` is actually a string, not an array, so even if it was passed you would still get an error on the `each` method.

Comment: I added the output in the erb file `<% puts source[:blacklist].inspect %>`

Comment: Then I don't really understand why you're getting the error you do. You SHOULD be getting undefined method each for String...